# How to force http.client to send chunked-encoding HTTP body in python?

Tags: python, http, chunked

I want to send chunked HTTP body to test my own HTTP server.
So I wrote this python code:

```
import http.client

body = 'Hello World!' * 80

conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("some.domain.com")
url = "/some_path?arg=true_arg"

conn.request("POST", url, body, {"Transfer-Encoding":"chunked"})

resp = conn.getresponse()
print(resp.status, resp.reason)
```

I expect the HTTP request's body is transferrd chunked, 
but I capture the network package with Wireshark, the HTTP request's body is not transferred chunked.

**How to transfer chunked body by http.client lib in python?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, I get it.

First, write my own chunked encode function.

Then use putrequest(), putheader(), endheaders() and send() instead of request()

```
import http.client

def chunk_data(data, chunk_size):
    dl = len(data)
    ret = ""
    for i in range(dl // chunk_size):
        ret += "%s\r\n" % (hex(chunk_size)[2:])
        ret += "%s\r\n\r\n" % (data[i * chunk_size : (i + 1) * chunk_size])

    if len(data) % chunk_size != 0:
        ret += "%s\r\n" % (hex(len(data) % chunk_size)[2:])
        ret += "%s\r\n" % (data[-(len(data) % chunk_size):])

    ret += "0\r\n\r\n"
    return ret


conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(host)
url = "/some_path"
conn.putrequest('POST', url)
conn.putheader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked')
conn.endheaders()
conn.send(chunk_data(body, size_per_chunk).encode('utf-8'))

resp = conn.getresponse()
print(resp.status, resp.reason)
conn.close()
```

Comment: works better for me whith only one separator in the second line inside the for of chunk_data (ie: ret += "%s\r\n" % (data[i * chunk_size : (i + 1) * chunk_size]))

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that if you already know the size of your data like in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9238565/241294) given you could just set the `Content-Length` and send it all back in one hit, which is kind of what you're doing with the single call to `conn.send` anyway.

Chunked transfer encoding is most useful when you don't know how big the data is e.g. dynamically generated content. I've modified your code to illustrate:

```
import httplib

def write_chunk(conn, data):
    conn.send("%s\r\n" % hex(len(data))[2:])
    conn.send("%s\r\n" % data)

def dynamically_generate_data():
    for i in range(80):
        yield "hello world"

conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("localhost")
url = "/some_path"
conn.putrequest('POST', url)
conn.putheader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked')
conn.endheaders()

for new_chunk in dynamically_generate_data():
    write_chunk(conn, new_chunk)
conn.send('0\r\n')

resp = conn.getresponse()
print(resp.status, resp.reason)
conn.close()
```