# How to POST chunked encoded data in Python

Tags: python, http, python-requests, httplib, chunked-encoding

I am trying to POST chunked encoded data to httpbin.org/post. I tried two options: Requests and httplib

## Using Requests

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests

def gen():
        l = range(130)
        for i in l:
                yield '%d' % i

if __name__ == "__main__":
        url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
        headers = {
                        'Transfer-encoding':'chunked',
                        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
                        'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
                        #'User-Agent': 'ExpressionEncoder'
                }
        r = requests.post(url, headers = headers, data = gen())
        print r
```

## Using httplib

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import httplib
import os.path

if __name__ == "__main__":
        conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('httpbin.org')
        conn.connect()
        conn.putrequest('POST', '/post')
        conn.putheader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked')
        conn.putheader('Connection', 'Keep-Alive')
        conn.putheader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
        conn.endheaders()
        for i in range(130):
                conn.send(str(i))

        r = conn.getresponse()
        print r.status, r.reason
```

In both of these cases, whenever I analyze Wireshark traces, I do not see multiple chunks being sent. Instead, what I see is that all of the data is being sent in a single chunk? Am I missing something here?

Comment: [How to force http.client to send chunked-encoding HTTP body in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9237961/95735)

Comment: Are you sure? Selecting the single HTTP message in Wireshark, you should be able to expand the Hypertext Transfer Protocol portion. That expanded part should have another subheader called 'HTTP chunked response', which contains your data.

Comment: @Lukasa: Yeah, you are right. For some reason, my understanding of how chunked data appears on Wireshark was flawed. I thought it always appears as a separate packet. Thanks for your time.

Comment: with httplib do you need to print the length of the chunks line by line, too?

Comment: It worked correctly. I was expecting to see separate trace for each group of chunks on the pcap which does not happen.

Answer (score 3):

The code you posted shouldn't have worked correctly. The reason you still get a successful response back is because httpbin.org doesn't currently support chunked transfer encoding. See bug https://github.com/kennethreitz/httpbin/issues/102.

Like in the post [Piotr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661962/how-to-post-chunked-encoded-data-in-python?lq=1#comment25729687_17661962) linked to above, you're supposed to write out the length of each chunk in hexadecimal and then the chunk itself.

I butchered your code for an example. The http://httpbin.org/post endpoint has [a form that you can use for testing](http://httpbin.org/forms/post). That's where I generated the `chunk1` and `chunk2` form data.

```
import httplib
import time

chunk1 = "custname=bob&custtel=11111&custemail=bob%40email.com&si"
chunk2 = "ze=medium&topping=bacon&delivery=11%3A00&comments=if+you%27re+late+we+get+it+free"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('httpbin.org')
    conn.connect()
    conn.putrequest('POST', '/post')
    conn.putheader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked')
    conn.putheader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    conn.endheaders()

    conn.send("%s\r\n" % hex(len(chunk1))[2:])
    conn.send("%s\r\n" % chunk1)

    time.sleep(1)

    conn.send("%s\r\n" % hex(len(chunk2))[2:])
    conn.send("%s\r\n" % chunk2)

    time.sleep(1)
    /* last chunk */
    conn.send("0\r\n\r\n")

    r = conn.getresponse()
    print r.status, r.reason, r.read()
```

The stream in wireshark will look something like the following which is incorrect as it's not waiting for (notice the trailing `0`) or interpreting the request body (notice the `json: null`) that we sent:

```
POST /post HTTP/1.1
Host: httpbin.org
Accept-Encoding: identity
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

37
custname=bob&custtel=11111&custemail=bob%40email.com&si
51
ze=medium&topping=bacon&delivery=11%3A00&comments=if+you%27re+late+we+get+it+free
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Server: gunicorn/18.0
Date: Fri, 31 Oct 2014 10:37:24 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 494
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Via: 1.1 vegur

{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept-Encoding": "identity", 
    "Connect-Time": "2", 
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Total-Route-Time": "0", 
    "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked", 
    "Via": "1.1 vegur", 
    "X-Request-Id": "5053a365-ca6a-4c29-b97a-f7a6ded7f2d9"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "110.174.97.16", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}0
```